# No result shown when calling another function into main function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple Interactive Fiction game using HTML, CSS, and Javascript(no jQuery) only. So far for the UI and event handling there are no problems, but this current piece of code doesn't particularly work for me.

```
function x(){
  var race = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
  var gender = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
  var y = document.getElementById("paragraph");
  encounterText.textContent = "";
  switch (race) {
    case 0:
      if(gender === 0)
        y.textContent += "You meet a rabbit girl.";
        a();
        else {
        y.textContent += "You meet a rabbit boy.";
        }
      break;
default:
  if(gender === 0)
    y.textContent += "You meet a human girl.";
    a();
    else {
      y.textContent += "You meet a human boy.";
    }
  }
}
function a(){
  var hairGen = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
  var y = document.getElementById("randomEncounter");
  switch (hairGen) {
    case 0:
    y.textContent += "She has a long hair";
      break;
    default:
    y.textContent += "She has a short hair";
  }

}
```

When the event runs, there are nothing to show on the paragraph. 
Did I do something wrong with the Javascript?

PS: I'm a Javascript beginner.

Comment: What errors do you see in the console? Where did you define `encounterText`?

Comment: You have syntax errors. `else` statements with no corresponding `if` statements. Use a [block statement](https://www.google.ca/search?q=mdn+block+statement&oq=mdn+block+statement&aqs=chrome..69i57.2047j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) (curly-braces) for your `if` body if you want to have more than one statement inside the `if` condition. Your code reads like this: `if(gender === 0) { y.textContent += "You meet a rabbit girl."; } a(); else {` in two places, which is a syntax error.

Comment: @Paulpro You sir, thank you for the curly brace reminder. I must have deleted it somewhere when I write the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check your console. There are obvious errors here.

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else

Here's a fiddle with it working. You just have to wrap the block after the first if statement in curly brackets. eg:

```
if(gender === 0) {
    y.textContent += "You meet a rabbit girl.";
    a();
 }   else {
    y.textContent += "You meet a rabbit boy.";
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/df13beya/7/

Comment: Indeed as @Paulpro pointed out, I must have somehow deleted the curly-braces when I'm writing the code. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: Yeah no problem just make sure you check your console man. Should always be the first source of information when things go wrong.